# Get data model diagram from OPC UA Server

Tags: diagram, opc-ua

Is there a tool that I can use to connect to an existing OPC UA Server and get its data model, creating a nice diagram using the OPC UA graphical notation?
I'm asking this because I'm used to make UML diagrams but the OPC UA graphical notation is quite different and I also couldn't find a good drawing tool using this notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is one Client provided by Unified Automation by which you can connect to your server and see the graphical representation of the information model exposed.

Click [here](https://www.unified-automation.com/downloads/opc-ua-clients.html) to Download UaExpert